# Calculate Apache's response time for last 10 seconds

Tags: text-processing

I have the next apache's log format:

`LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""`

where's `%D` - The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.

I want to know how can I get an average response time for last 10 seconds. Somehow a script or something should calculate the number of requests for last 10 seconds and summarize the response time. The result should be: number_of_requests_for_last_10_seconds / sum_of_request_time_for_last_10_seconds.

Is that possible to do with awk or something? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Log's sample:

```
93.182.72.47 - - [19/Aug/2014:02:24:19 -0700] "GET /test/085 HTTP/1.1" 200 1006 445 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
119.232.112.148 - - [19/Aug/2014:02:24:19 -0700] "GET /test/003 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 84234 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
85.244.38.232 - - [19/Aug/2014:02:24:19 -0700] "GET /test/332 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 75760 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
236.131.91.87 - - [19/Aug/2014:02:24:16 -0700] "GET /test/006 HTTP/1.1" 200 32 3640965 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64"
112.241.72.130 - - [19/Aug/2014:02:24:19 -0700] "GET /test/042 HTTP/1.1" 200 50 1148668 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64"
```

**UPDATE2**

```
tailf /var/log/httpd/access_log | perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
   BEGIN{$threshold = (localtime) - 10}
   if (/\[(.*?)\] ".*?" \d+ \d+ (\d+)/) {
     $d = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z");print $d->datetime." ".$threshold->datetime;
     if ($d >= $threshold) {$t += $2; $n++}
   }
   END{print $t/$n if $n}' /var/log/httpd/access_log

...
2014-08-19T03:54:42 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:43 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:43 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:42 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:43 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:43 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:43 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:43 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:45 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:45 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:45 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:44 2014-08-19T03:54:27
2014-08-19T03:54:46 2014-08-19T03:54:27
```

Comment: Seeing your `tailf`, do you mean that you want a running average to be constantly updated as new line are being added to the file? Or a one of invocation that gives you the average for the last 10 seconds?

Comment: Please check similar problem: [How to calculate and group the time differences of specified syscalls when running strace](http://superuser.com/questions/459005/how-to-calculate-and-group-the-time-differences-of-specified-syscalls-when-runni) and solved by using awk. Or: [How to extract two numbers from two strings and calculate the difference in Bash?](http://superuser.com/questions/367132/how-to-extract-two-numbers-from-two-strings-and-calculate-the-difference-in-bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typical job for `perl`:

With Time::Piece 1.17 and above (`perl` 5.12 and above):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
   BEGIN{$threshold = (localtime) - 10}
   if (/\[(.*?)\] ".*?" \d+ \d+ (\d+)/) {
     $d = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z");
     if ($d >= $threshold) {$t += $2; $n++}
   }
   END{print $t/$n if $n}' your-file.log
```

Versions of Time::Piece 1.15 and below didn't support `%z`, so, there, assuming the caller's timezone matches that of the log file, you could do instead:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
   BEGIN{$threshold = (localtime) - 10}
   if (/\[([^]]*:\d+).*?".*?" \d+ \d+ (\d+)/) {
     $d = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S");
     if ($d->datetime ge $threshold->datetime) {$t += $2; $n++}
   }
   END{print $t/$n if $n}' your-file.log
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work for me, no output. seems $n is always null

Comment: @KennyPowers, did you try it on log lines that are less than 10 seconds old. The above works for me on your sample above if I replace `10` with `10000` (now at 10:24 GMT)

Comment: still doesn't work :( i'm newbie in perl, sorry

Comment: @KennyPowers Can you try a `tail your-log | cmd` where `cmd` is the perl command above but with `print $d->datetime." ".$threshold->datetime;` inserted before the `if ($d >=...`? Gives UTC times, that may clarify why you don't see anything.

Comment: I have updated my question with the results

Comment: @KennyPowers, thanks. What about `tail` instead of `tailf` instead? From that, we can see the dates are greater than the thresholds, so I can't explain why you wouldn't get anything. Of course with `tailf` (assuming it's some sort of `tail -f`), the `END` part is never reached.

Comment: `tail` gives the same results. I have tried to change `if ($d...` to `if ($d >= $threshold) {$t += $2; $n++; print "ta-da"}`, no "ta-da" in output. Very strange as I can see from the previous try that $d is greater then $theshold

Comment: Ok seems this works, `if ($d->datetime >= $threshold->datetime) {$t += $2; $n++}` but i'm not sure why :) change your answer accordingly, and thanks!

Comment: @KennyPowers. Sorry I was wrong. `datetime` doesn't show UTC times. It show UTC time for the result of strptime, but local time for $threshold. So it would seem that there's a discrepancy there. Your latest edit was at 11:04 UTC. Your logs have -0700, so the 3.54 there is incorrect. It should probably have been 10:54. It's possible that you're using a version of `perl` whose Time::Piece doesn't support %z. What's your version of `perl`?

Comment: `perl -v` says v5.10.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16529/discussion-between-kennypowers-and-stephane-chazelas).